# Mongoose: Count removed documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How can I check if the remove-method of a Mongoose model really has removed something?

```
MyModel.remove({_id: myId}, function(err, entry) {
  if(entry == null) next(new Error("ID was not found."));    // this doesn't work
}
```

Can I check how many documents were removed?

In the [Mongo-Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Removing) kristina1 write in a comment:

> If you call db.runCommand({getLastError:1}) after a remove and the "n" field will tell you how many documents were deleted.

But I don't know how to do this with Mongoose.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Mongoose < 4, MongoDB < 3**

The second parameter to the `remove` callback is a number containing the number of documents removed.

```
MyModel.remove({_id: myId}, function(err, numberRemoved) {
  if(numberRemoved === 0) next(new Error("ID was not found."));
}
```

**Mongoose 4.x, MongoDB 3.x**

The second parameter passed to the `remove` callback is now an object with the `result.n` field indicating the count of removed documents:

```
MyModel.remove({_id: myId}, function(err, obj) {
  if(obj.result.n === 0) next(new Error("ID was not found."));
}
```

Comment: So weird that Mongoose documentation doesn't have this parameter. +1

Comment: This doesn't look valid in recent versions of Mongoose. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: @warriorpostman It's still valid in 3.8.21; I tried it just now.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK! Looks like I had mis-ordered the function params.

Comment: This answer is wrong. At least for Mongoose version >= 4.1.3. In `MyModel.remove({_id: myId}, function(param1, param2)` , the `param2` parameter is an object that looks like this : `{"ok":1,"n":0,"lastOp":"6219670646759096321","electionId":"562d1c70d1c0756238aaabb9"}`. Mongoose is horrible when it comes to documentation and there's no explanation as to what the above contents mean.

Comment: @SproutCoder See updated answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If this didn't work for you try `obj.n` I think there's no longer a result wrapper /shrug

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with latest version of mongoose, and it did not work. As the second parameter comes back as operation result, not just count. Used as below, it worked :

```
 Model.remove({
            myId: req.myId
        }, function(err, removeResult) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (removeResult.result.n == 0) {
                console.log("Record not found");
            }
            Console.log("Deleted successfully.");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this in 2020 and found with Mongoose 5.9.28 that the result no longer requires a result wrapper, so using remove to get a count of deleted records in an async method looks like:

```js
async function remove(query) {
  const result = await ItemModel.remove(query);
  return result.n;
}
```

Of course, collection.remove is deprecated in favor of deleteOne or deleteMany, so try this as well.